# Evaluate Equation in Cell Array, MATLAB

Tags: matlab, cell-array, differential-equations

I have a cell array containing functions (with function handle) and I want to evaluate these inside a for-loop. I want to evaluate the differential equations:
x1'= x2,
x2' = ax2-bx1

My code is like this:

```
init = [0,0];
F = {@(x1,x2) x2,@(x1,x2)(a*x2-b*x1)};
X0 = init;

for i=1:10
   X = X0 + c*F(init(1),init(2));
   X0 = X;
   init[1] = {X(1)};
   init[2] = {X(2)};
end
```

The constants a,b and c are given.

I get the error:

```
Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: which line is causing the error? Please do some initial debugging yourself by adding print statements or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there are two other problems with your code: `c` is not defined and you are trying to index into `init` with `[]`-brackets, which will throw:

```
Error: File: foo Line: 8 Column: 8
Unbalanced or unexpected parenthesis or bracket.
```

The subscript error occurs because you are trying to access `F(0,0)` because `init(1)` and `init(2)` are `0`. Remember that the way you declared F, it is a cell array:

```
>> F = {@(x1,x2) x2,@(x1,x2)(a*x2-b*x1)};
>> whos F
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class    Attributes

  F         1x2               288  cell
```

Hence, `F(0,0)` is illegal because indexes in matlab start with `1`. Your functions reside in `F{1}` and `F{2}`.

```
>> F{1}
ans = 
    @(x1,x2)x2
>> F{2}
ans = 
    @(x1,x2)(a*x2-b*x1)
>> f = F{1}
f = 
    @(x1,x2)x2
>> f(0,0)
ans =
     0
```

Answer (score 1):

`F` is a 1x2 cell array.  To access elements (in your case, function handles) within this array you must use the curly braces `{}` to do so.  For example, the first function is retrieved by `F{1}` and the second by `F{2}` using positive integer indices.

In your example, `init` is a 1x2 array of zeros so when the code evaluates

```
F(init(1),init(2));
```

it is trying to access something within `F` using indices that are **not** positive.  Hence the error.

I suspect that you will need to do something like the following in your `for` loop and evaluate each function separately

```
for i=1:10
    for j=1:2
        % get the jth function handle
        func = F{j};

        % evaluate
        X(j) =  X0(j) + c*func(init(1),init(2));

        % save 
     end
 end
```

I've left the *save** portion to be filled in by you because it isn't all that clear to me why there are the different `init`,`X0` and `X` variables - could you consolidate them?

Note also your mixture of `[]` and `()` brackets when accessing arrays.  In MATLAB, if the array is of type cell, then we use the `{}` to access elements.  For all other arrays, we use the `()` brackets.